# Почему heroku не хочет загружать мой проект?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Я добавил в проект файлы

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn myfist.wsgi --log-file -
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.6
```

Еще я пробовал

```
python-3.7.4
python-3.7.8
python-3.6.1
```

.gitignore

```
__pycache__/
*pyc
db.sqlite3
```

reqirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.3
djangorestframework==3.11.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.14.0
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
```

Я закомментировал свой проект и отправил по

```
git push heroku master
```

Но я получаю ошибку

```
Enumerating objects: 50, done.
Counting objects: 100% (50/50), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (50/50), 14.01 KiB | 421.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 50 (delta 10), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildp...
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#d...
remote:
remote: ! Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: ! Push rejected to shielded-bastion-00322.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/shielded-bastion-00322.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielded-bastion-00322.git'
```

Я уже пробовал переустановить buildpack

```
heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Не помогло

Comment: Пользуйтесь поиском. Только по ru.so.com по запросу `[heroku] failed to push some refs to` можно найти вот эти вопросы c ответами и комментариями: [1](https://goo.su/1WGh), [2](https://goo.su/1WGH), [3](https://goo.su/1wgi), [4](https://goo.su/1wGI), [5](https://goo.su/1WgI)

Comment: @cauf Ответы 1 и 2. У меня уже есть эти файлы. Ответ 3 в моем репозитории уже есть файлы. Ответ 4 Не относится к моему вопросу. Ответ 5 Я уже читал  оф.инфо не помогло.